# Unable to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, django

New Djangonaut here.

I'm working on a new application. I need to register some entries from a log on a daily basis. I have setup the application and my models and everything is working smoothly from the admin page. However, I want to write a script that automates the process of bulk-inserting the data into the database.

I wrote the script and set it to insert just one record to check whether it is working or not. when I run it I get this issue:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must
either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I tried speechifying it inside my code using all the following options:

```
setup_environ(settings)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
settings.configure()
```

nothing is working ..

when I copy my code line by line into the shell interpreter of manage.py it works fine!

I'm using django 1.6 and python 2.6.6

Please help

Thanks!

Comment: Where is located your bulk inserting script?  You could put it inside one of your Django apps and call it with `manage.py`, using [`BaseCommand`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).  It would spare you the whole settings importing process.

Comment: `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myapp.settings" python manage.py`might be better approach